# Failed on insert entity with many related entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

This is my first post because until now I had always found solution with your answers, until now...

I have three Entities (Bike, Category and Extra) that have some field translatable. I know there is a Translatable Extension in symfony but I discovered a bit late and I have my solution always working.

The thing is I have then 3 other tables (BikeI18N, CategoryI18N and ExtraI18N). These table link with their associated with a column bike_id (for example). Here you have the schema of Bike and Category and their I18N's tables:

Bike:

```
BEM\BikeBundle\Entity\Bike:
type: entity
table: null
fields:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
    marca:
        type: string
        length: 255
    model:
        type: string
        length: 255
    preu1Dia:
        type: float
        column: preu_1dia
    [...]
manyToOne:
  category:
    targetEntity: BEM\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category
    inversedBy: bikes 
oneToMany:
  translation:
    targetEntity: BikeI18N
    mappedBy: bike
    cascade: [persist]        
  pedals:
    targetEntity: Pedal
    mappedBy: bike
  talles:
    targetEntity: Talla
    mappedBy: bike
manyToMany:
  accessoris:
    targetEntity: Accessori
    inversedBy: bikes      
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

BikeI18N:

```
BEM\BikeBundle\Entity\BikeI18N:
type: entity
table: null
fields:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
    descripcio:
        type: text
    locale:
        type: string
        length: '2'
manyToOne:
  bike:
    targetEntity: Bike
    inversedBy: translation  
    joinColumn:
      bike_id:
        referencedColumnName: id        
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Category:

```
BEM\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: BEM\CategoryBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository
fields:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
oneToMany:
  translation:
    targetEntity: CategoryI18N
    mappedBy: category
    cascade: [persist]
  bikes:
    targetEntity: BEM\BikeBundle\Entity\Bike
    mappedBy: category
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

and finally CategoryI18N:

```
BEM\CategoryBundle\Entity\CategoryI18N:
type: entity
table: null
fields:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
    categoryId:
        type: integer
        column: category_id
    locale:
        type: string
        length: '2'
    translation:
        type: string
        length: 255
manyToOne:
  category:
    targetEntity: Category
    inversedBy: translation
    joinColumn:
      category_id:
        referencedColumnName: id        
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

In my "new" form I have a Category form with 4 embeded CategoryI18N forms. It works properly. The problem is the Bike and BikeI18N does not even if I did the same.

If I write `$translation->setAccessori($this);` in `Bike::addTranslation(BikeI18N $translation)` I get the error **Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?**.

If I don't write `$translation->setAccessori($this);` **the form is saved but the relation is lost** or, if I set the DB to `not_nullable bike_id` I get an error.

The most surprising thing that makes no sense to me is that I have `setCategory($this)` inside the addTranslation of the class Category...any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is related to your schema setup, please provide the controller code which you are using when the Error occurs.

Comment: Thanks m0c for answering. I did not see your activity. I logged in to inform I found the problem and I realized you tried to help. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue.

The think was in my BikeI18N form builder.

```
    class BikeI18NType extends AbstractType
    {
       public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
         {
            $builder
            ->add('descripcio')
            ->add('locale', 'hidden')
            //->add('bike', 'hidden')
           ;
         }
     }
```

When I commented out the bike additions the problem was solved.

Thanks for reading!